# AngularJS Trigger callback after ForEach

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently developing an AngularJS form which on submit pushes single or multiple participant data to an SQL database.

I'm able to push data to the SQL database, but I'm wanting to trigger a callback that redirects the user once all participant data has been successfully submitted.

At the moment on success it redirects the user but, misses the next foreach submit for the next participant.

Any and all advice would be appreciated.

**AngularJS**

```
/* Submit */
$scope.submit = function() {

  var array = $scope.form.participants;
  //console.log(array);

  angular.forEach(array, function(value, key){
    var request = $http({
      method: "post",
      url: 'http://xxx.co.uk/submit.php',
      data: {
        coachName: $scope.form.program.coachName,
        contactArea: $scope.form.program.contractArea,
        postcode: $scope.form.program.postcode,
        programmeStart: $scope.form.program.programmeDate,
        sessionDate: $scope.form.program.sessionDate,
        sessionNumber: $scope.form.program.sessionNumber,
        weekNumber: $scope.form.program.weekNumber,
        id: value.participant.id,
        attendance: value.participant.attendance,
        weight: value.participant.weight,
        goldBehaviours: value.participant.goldBehaviours,
        stepCount: value.participant.stepCount,
        creditData: value.participant.creditData,
        weekOne: value.participant.weekOne,
        stepOne: value.participant.stepOne,
        weekTwo: value.participant.weekTwo,
        stepTwo: value.participant.stepTwo,
        weekThree: value.participant.weekThree,
        stepThree: value.participant.stepThree,
        weekFour: value.participant.weekFour,
        stepFour: value.participant.stepFour,
        weekFive: value.participant.weekFive,
        stepFive: value.participant.stepFive
      },
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).success(function(data) {
      //console.log(data);
      $location.path("/thankyou");
    });
  });
};
```

**Data**

```
  {
    "program":{
    "coachName":"AD",
    "contractArea":"Berkshire",
    "postcode":"NN1",
    "programmeDate":"2016-08-15T23:00:00.000Z",
    "sessionDate":"2016-08-16T23:00:00.000Z",
    "sessionNumber":"1",
    "weekNumber":"2"
    },"participants":[
      {"participant":{"id":"AW01","attendance":"Did Not Attend","weight":"1","goldBehaviours":"2","stepCount":"3","creditData":"","weekOne":"4","stepOne":"4","weekTwo":"5","stepTwo":"5","weekThree":"6","stepThree":"6","weekFour":"7","stepFour":"7","weekFive":"8","stepFive":"8"}},
      {"participant":{"id":"AW02","attendance":"Attended","weight":"2","goldBehaviours":"3","stepCount":"4","creditData":"","weekOne":"5","stepOne":"5","weekTwo":"6","stepTwo":"6","weekThree":"7","stepThree":"7","weekFour":"8","stepFour":"8","weekFive":"9","stepFive":"9"}}
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to your controller/service and use `$q.all` method (you can also use native Javascript `Promise` if you're not worried about old browsers support).

The `all` method takes an array of promises and resolve when all promises in the array resolve (it will reject if any of the promises reject).

```
$scope.submit = function() {

  var array = $scope.form.participants;
  var promises = [];
  //console.log(array);

  angular.forEach(array, function(value, key){
    promises.push($http({
      method: "post",
      url: 'http://xxx.co.uk/submit.php',
      data: {
        coachName: $scope.form.program.coachName,
        ...
        ...
        ...
        stepFive: value.participant.stepFive
      },
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }));        
  });
  $q.all(promises).then(function() {
    $location.path("/thankyou");
  });
};
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you Yarons!

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to redirect with each iteration, not after all iterations have been completed.  Try moving your redirect like so:

```
angular.forEach(array, function(value, key){
var request = $http({
  method: "post",
  url: 'http://xxx.co.uk/submit.php',
  data: {
    coachName: $scope.form.program.coachName,
    contactArea: $scope.form.program.contractArea,
    postcode: $scope.form.program.postcode,
    programmeStart: $scope.form.program.programmeDate,
    sessionDate: $scope.form.program.sessionDate,
    sessionNumber: $scope.form.program.sessionNumber,
    weekNumber: $scope.form.program.weekNumber,
    id: value.participant.id,
    attendance: value.participant.attendance,
    weight: value.participant.weight,
    goldBehaviours: value.participant.goldBehaviours,
    stepCount: value.participant.stepCount,
    creditData: value.participant.creditData,
    weekOne: value.participant.weekOne,
    stepOne: value.participant.stepOne,
    weekTwo: value.participant.weekTwo,
    stepTwo: value.participant.stepTwo,
    weekThree: value.participant.weekThree,
    stepThree: value.participant.stepThree,
    weekFour: value.participant.weekFour,
    stepFour: value.participant.stepFour,
    weekFive: value.participant.weekFive,
    stepFive: value.participant.stepFive
  },
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).success(function(data) {
  //console.log(data);

});
$location.path("/thankyou");


 });
```

Your redirect needs to be outside of your forEach.

Comment: This will redirect instantly.